# Pass a list of characters as parameter to RScript in VBA?

Tags: r, vba, shell, parameters

I have a R script that works fine, with one of its variables being set as such :

```
Benchmark <- c("Bench1","Bench2","Bench3","Bench4","Bench5","Bench6")

Benchmark
[1] "Bench1"   "Bench2"   "Bench3"   "Bench4"   "Bench5"   "Bench6"
```

Later on in the code, I check in a table if one of its column has a value present in Benchmark :

```
CollStruc <- CollStruc[CollStruc$Designer %in% Benchmark,]
```

Until there, no problem. The issue here is I'd like to call the Rscript from VBA, thanks to this code :

```vb
Dim shell As Object
Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
Dim style As Integer: style = 1
Dim errorCode As Integer

'Paramètres à passer à R
Dim CheminR As String, Benchmark As String

NbBench = WSExec.Range("C16").End(xlDown).Row - WSExec.Range("C16").Row

Benchmark = """" & WSExec.Range("C16").Value & """"
For i = 1 To NbBench
    Benchmark = Benchmark & "," & """" & WSExec.Range("C16").Offset(i, 0).Value & """"
Next i

Dim path As String
path = "RScript \\Tagwalk-nas\public\R-Scripts\Brand_Equity-Benchmark-parameters.R " & Benchmark

errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
```

I've been passing arguments in RScript with lines such as these :

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=T)
Benchmark <- c(args[1])
```

And this is where things go wrong. My Benchmark variable doesn't look the way I expect it to, and so the rest of the code returns errors

> Benchmark 
>   "1" "Bench1,Bench2,Bench3,Bench4,Bench5,Bench6"

Do you know how I can make this work ? 
Thanks

EDIT : 
Thanks Adam and Parfait for your help.

The variable Benchmark created in VBA now looks like this :

```
print.debug(Benchmark)
"Bench1,Bench2,Bench3,Bench4,Bench5,Bench6"
```

I've tried using unlist as suggested by Adam, and it seems to transform the variable as I'd like.
Here is the variable when I use it in R :

```
str(Benchmark)
chr [1:6] "gucci" "louis-vuitton" "chanel" "christian-dior" "prada" "fendi"
```

and here is the output provided by `sink()` I get when putting `str(Benchmark)` in my Rscript executed from VBA :

```
 chr [1:6] "gucci" "louis-vuitton" "chanel" "christian-dior" "prada" ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a comma separated list. I can't replicate your project so this'll be a partial answer.

Once you have `Benchmark <- "Bench1,Bench2,Bench3,Bench4,Bench5,Bench6"` the problem becomes pretty easy. I can't tell from your question what the structure of Benchmark is after you try running the script. So you might need to clean it up or `unlist()` it before you are ready.

Then,

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

Benchmark <- unlist(strsplit(args[1],","))
#[1] "Bench1" "Bench2" "Bench3" "Bench4" "Bench5" "Bench6"
```

Comment: Can you do a `str(Benchmark)` or something else so we can see what is in your variable? Otherwise, I don't have your excel sheet. I'd have to try to create one that would work with your code before I could get your VBA to run. And it's probably just that you don't understand the different types of r variables.

Comment: I am not the OP. I was suggesting you show the `commandArgs` to help OP connect his/her to yours.

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. Losing steam here on a Friday.